# App runs very slow on ios6 devices

Tags: ios6

I have an app with deployment target iOS 3.0. It runs smooth as silk on all devices that haven't been upgraded to iOS6. However, on iOS6, animations are laggy, scrolling tableviews is slow (doesn't matter if they contain a lot of data or not, very inconsistent).

I have been going through the code and can't seem to find anything that causes this laggyness. ARC is disabled for this project (because it still supports iOS3.0), I have changed the deployment target to iOS6 to see if that'd make any change but it didn't.

Any developers with a similar problem? I'm starting to think it may be a setting in my Xcode project, as the laggyness is very inconsistent; Some screen work smooth on iPhone 5, while the same screens lag on iPhone 4 (and vice versa!)

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: there was a background image "stripe.png" that was repeated via

```
[bgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stripe.png"]]];
```

The stripe.png file was 3x3 in size. A @2x version was provided, but it had the same size (3x3). When I made a 6x6 version of it, everything runs smooth again.

**Always make your @2x images double the size!**